# Update information is outdated when automatic updates set to 'Never'

Tags: updates

Numerous posts address this error, but none I found address its occurrence when automatic updates are set to 'Never'.  I have a server that performs a very limited role, and I don't want it updating itself.  Periodically when I sign into the server I see the red triangle, which is removed by running updates, fine.  But should this error keep showing when automatic updates are turned off?

Comment: Yes. It's a warning, not an error. The system is simply reminding you to run package update...because it cannot.

Comment: Thank you.  Also, I've noticed when I change those update settings, I get a popup that says my update information is out of date, even when it's not.  A bug perhaps?  Lastly, when check for updates is set to 'Never', does it even matter what the other settings are (e.g. download, download and install, etc.)?

Comment: There's a difference between a package database *update* and a package *upgrade*. When you change your update settings, then your old package database becomes *by definition* obsolete and should be updated immediately. Changing the period of upgrades to 'Never' can be unwise - you are not getting security upgrades anymore...so seems like you need the reminder more than ever.

Comment: First, thanks for the advice.  I'm using Ubuntu on a hi-res music server, and I really don't want it to update itself, as it serves a very specific, low-security purpose behind the firewall of my home LAN.  Occasionally I rebuild it and get latest, but once it's up I don't want it changing (esp. during playback).  That said, this Linux novice is open to other opinions.  So you're saying to always run an update right after changing those settings?

Comment: Seems like you are tracking accurately.